# p:commandLink action only working for first link

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here is my XHTML code :

```
<ui:repeat var="clinic" value="#{searchController.clinicsViewList}">
    <h:form rendered="#{clinic.timingSlot.size() gt 0 ?true:false}" id="lessSlotForm">
        <p:scrollPanel style="height:55px;overflow:hidden;overflow-x: scroll;white-space: nowrap;">
            <ui:repeat var="slot" value="#{clinic.timingSlot}">
                <p:commandLink value="#{slot.slotTime}"
                               action="#{appController.bookAppointmentSlot(slot , clinic)}"
                               disabled="#{slot.active eq 'true'?false:true}"
                               style="margin:5px;" >
                </p:commandLink>
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:scrollPanel>
    </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

Here is `<ui:repeat>` to display different clinics, in side `<ui:repeat>` is to display time slots for each clinics.

Here is inside `<ui:repeat>`, `<p:commandLink>` has action to display all time slots for clinic.

But here got displayed list of timeslots for all clinics. but when i click on 1st clinic timeslots(`<p:commandLink>`) is working fine.
but 2nd clinic time slots(`<p:commandLink>`) not working. 
Can any one tell me what is the reason.

Comment: @tt_dev: if it is a duplicate, you can mark it as such in the flagging

Comment: @Kukeltje: i already did, thank you.

Comment: @tt_dev Remarkable. I did to but it does not show up anywhere. Not as duplicate nor the 'possibly duplicate of'. Does someone not consider it a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

This is happing because your h:form is inside ui: repeat keep your form outside of ui: repeat

Comment: Thanks, but this is just what is referred to in the comment above. Please flag it as,a duplicate then. No need to answer it